# SMTP server not working, running on Node.js with Mailin package

Tags: node.js, email, dns, smtp

I followed the [Mailin docs](http://mailin.io/doc) but haven't been able to make it work.

My domain is: aryan.ml

I'm using Amazon Route 53 for DNS configurations. Here's a screenshot of that:
[image: Amazon Route 53 DNS configurations]

On my app.js file I'm running the sample code given by the official Mailin docs as well. The code is under "Embedded inside a node application" heading at http://mailin.io/doc

```js
var mailin = require('mailin');

mailin.start({
  port: 25,
  disableWebhook: true // Disable the webhook posting.
});

/* Access simplesmtp server instance. */
mailin.on('authorizeUser', function(connection, username, password, done) {
  if (username == "johnsmith" && password == "mysecret") {
    done(null, true);
  } else {
    done(new Error("Unauthorized!"), false);
  }
});

/* Event emitted when a connection with the Mailin smtp server is initiated. */
mailin.on('startMessage', function(connection) {
  /* connection = {
      from: 'sender@somedomain.com',
      to: 'someaddress@yourdomain.com',
      id: 't84h5ugf',
      authentication: { username: null, authenticated: false, status: 'NORMAL' }
  }
  }; */
  console.log(connection);
});

/* Event emitted after a message was received and parsed. */
mailin.on('message', function(connection, data, content) {
  console.log(data);
  /* Do something useful with the parsed message here.
   * Use parsed message `data` directly or use raw message `content`. */
});
```

I also tried testing my setup using mxtoolbox but it "Failed to connect" to my MX server. http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3amxemail.aryan.ml&run=toolpage

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure these two things are correct (for AWS):

1. Turns out it was my Amazon's security group that kept blocking port 25. If you're experiencing similar problems on AWS definitely make sure you allow traffic through port 25 of your server.
2. For Mailin package navigate to `/node_modules/mailin/lib/mailin.js` and change the default value of `host` to `0.0.0.0`, it's on line 27. This solves the problem on AWS.